# pandas.Series How to return the index of the closest date before the input date

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas.Series `s` like this

```
>>> print(s)
date
2008-02-18    21.40
2008-02-19    21.10
2008-02-20    20.40
2008-02-21    20.75
2008-02-22    21.35
2008-02-25    22.80
2008-02-26    23.20
2008-02-29    23.50
2008-03-03    24.00
2008-03-04    24.10
2008-03-05    23.85
2008-03-06    23.20
```

Note that some of its dates are missing. I mean `s.index` doesn't contain `2008-02-23`, `2008-02-24`, `2008-02-27`, `2008-03-01`, and `2008-03-02`.

How can I implement a function that has the following inputs and outputs:

```
input                   output

'2008-02-22 00:00:00'     4
'2008-02-23 00:00:00'     4
'2008-02-24 00:00:00'     4
'2008-02-25 00:00:00'     5
'2008-02-28 00:00:00'     6
```

This function outputs the index of the date of `s`. If the date is not found in `s`, it returns the index of the closest date before the input date.

I know that `s.index.get_loc(pd.Timestamp('2008-02-20 00:00:00'))` can return `2`, which is the index of `2008-02-20` of `s.index`. But this method doesn't work when its input is `'2008-02-24 00:00:00'`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy.searchsorted`
(https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)

```
x = pd.date_range('2000-01','2001-01', freq = 'M')

x
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-31', '2000-02-29', '2000-03-31', '2000-04-30', '2000-05-31', '2000-06-30', '2000-07-31',
           '2000-08-31', '2000-09-30', '2000-10-31', '2000-11-30', '2000-12-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')

y = pd.to_datetime(['2000-01-10','2000-03-14','2000-06-30','2000-07-15'])

np.searchsorted(x, y)
array([0, 2, 5, 6], dtype=int64)
```

You may need to change the function parameters or fine tune your results a bit to match exactly what your want.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the date you need to the index (`date` in `s`), filter only numbers less or equal to `zero` (previous closet date) and use [`argmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html) to get the index:

```
input = ['2008-02-22 00:00:00', '2008-02-23 00:00:00', '2008-02-24 00:00:00',
    '2008-02-25 00:00:00', '2008-02-28 00:00:00']

results = [(s.index - i)[(s.index - i).days <= 0].argmax() for i in input]

results
#[4, 4, 4, 5, 6]
```

**Note**:

Make sure your index is sorted and is a datetime object:

```
s.index = pd.to_datetime(s)
s.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary column that runs from 0 to end of the df, ... 0,1,2,3,...

```
 df = df.assign(temp=df.index.get_indexer(df.index))
```

the dates should also be converted to datetimes, using pandas to_datetime method.
after that, use pandas [asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asof.html) to get ur indices

```
df.asof(test.input)
            date    temp
input       
2008-02-22  21.35   4.0
2008-02-23  21.35   4.0
2008-02-24  21.35   4.0
2008-02-25  22.80   5.0
2008-02-28  23.20   6.0
```